# PHP Simple HTML Dom Access Elements Having Dynamic Class Name

Tags: php

I'm using the Simple HTML Dom library to fetch required elements from a website. But the issue is that with each request, they are adding random numbers to the class names of CSS. Here's the example:

```
    <style>
    .title-tag-{random number}{
    font-size:44px;
}
    </style>
    <h1 class="title-tag-{random number}">Awesome Title Here</h1>
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
require_once './simple_html_dom.php';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($dataHTML);
$title = $html->find('div[class=title-tag-864]', 0);
```

But it gives the blank output as the class name is changed dynamically on each request.

Any workaround?

Comment: `simple_html_dom` i assume it is a class name, can you show us code in this?

Comment: Sounds like they are trying to stop people using their content, so perhaps this is a hint that they don't want you to be able to read it.

Comment: @CodeBug have a look at the [docs](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the [Simple HTML DOM Documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) to get the content of element without class name.

**Option 1** : Getting with only tag without class name

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($dataHTML);
$heading_1 = $html->find('h1',0)->innertext;
```

**Option 2** : Using regex preg_match or preg_match_all

```
$html=' <style>
    .title-tag-{random number}{
    font-size:44px;
}
    </style>
    <h1 class="title-tag-4588559">Awesome Title Here</h1>
';
preg_match('#<h1 class="title-tag-[0-9]*">(.*?)</h1>#',$html,$match);
print_r($match);
```

the code above will output :

```
        Array
(
    [0] => <h1 class="title-tag-4588559">Awesome Title Here</h1>
    [1] => Awesome Title Here
)
```